# clear default text on form field elements for mobile site

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, blur, onfocus

Ok I'm using the [jQuery Mobile framework](http://jquerymobile.com/) and I would like to be able to use the default values in a text or text area as helper text. But on focus clear the text and keep the newly entered value. Also on re-focus (say they touch it again by mistake) not to clear the value again.

I'm including these

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script>
```

The example is not working

Adding this to the page itself: ([link to example](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-change-default-value-on-focus/))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.default-value').each(function() {
        var default_value = this.value;
        $(this).focus(function() {
            if(this.value == default_value) {
                this.value = '';
            }
        });
        $(this).blur(function() {
            if(this.value == '') {
                this.value = default_value;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the HTML (It's in a form tag as well)

```
<!-- Address 2 -->
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="address-2">Address 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="address-2" id="address-2" class="default-value" value="Apt #, Suite #, Floor #"  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get your code to work using jQuery 1.5 and jQuery Mobile 1.0a3. Did you include jQuery as well as jQuery Mobile? jQuery Mobile requires a version of jQuery to work.

Edit: I should note that I only tested this on the iPhone simulator, and not an actual device. The simulator was running iOS 4.0.1.

```
<head><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.js" type="text/javascript"></script></head>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="address-2">Address 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="address-2" id="address-2" class="default-value" value="Apt #, Suite #, Floor #"  />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.default-value').each(function() {
            var default_value = this.value;
            $(this).focus(function() {
                if(this.value == default_value) {
                    this.value = '';
                }
            });
            $(this).blur(function() {
                if(this.value == '') {
                    this.value = default_value;
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: yes I'm including the libs, everything else seems to be working but this. Testing from my local box in chrome

Comment: I've added the code I used above. Does this snippet work for you?

Comment: Actually! There's no document.ready() call. I sometimes forget this as well.

Comment: yep that helped. I needed to add the code after the HTML. is there a way to add the code in the header instead?

Comment: I usually put all of my JavaScript in the <head>. I include the code as an external script and then have everything init within a $(document).ready() anonymous function. See http://www.playandgive.ca/ for a pretty crazy example.

Answer (score 9):

For future generations: there's a thing called placeholder in HTML5

```
<input type="text" name="address-2" placeholder="Apt #, Suite #, Floor #"  />
```

Placeholder is currently supported in newest webkit-based browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Further to HTML5's input placeholder attribute, which behaves exactly as the *helper text* you describe; jQuery Mobile recommends using the label field with the class "ui-hidden-accessible":

> For the sake of accessibility, jQuery Mobile requires that all form
>   elements be paired with a meaningful label

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/forms/docs-forms.html

You can then use Modernizr to detect the support for the placeholder attribute and if it is not supported, use a polyfill ([like this one](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-html5-placeholder-text)) or remove the ui-hidden-accessible class which will display the labels.

```
if(!Modernizr.input.placeholder){
$('label.ui-hidden-accessible')
    .removeClass('ui-hidden-accessible')
    .addClass('ui-accessible');
}
```

then style the new label as desired. I've found the polyfill approach doesn't work well when the input field is type="password", so unhiding the label is better in that case.